# How can I create a list that with two different styles in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I'm sorry if this is too basic for you, but I have completed the Free Code Camp course for HTML/CSS and I'm trying to do the projects and I'm struggling a lot :(.

I want to create a list like this:

- **1943** - ipsum derigam sursus versum
- **1975** - ipsum sharingan leviosa

But I want to be able to style the date and the content separately, and also to add the " - " automatically, so I would just add only the date in each list instance and only the content for the information.

I tried using a list within a list, and creating a table, also the after pseudo element to add the " - " to the date but I can't make this work right.

Can anyone with more HTML/CSS experience help me with this please?

Comment: Show us your attempts at the pseudo element, tables, and list-within-a-list. It's hard to know what you're doing incorrectly if you don't show any of it.

Comment: SO is not an ongoing discussion board or a code writing service. [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you want.

```css
.date {
  font-weight: bold       /* Makes the date bold */
  /* Add date styling here */
}

.content {
  /* Add content style here */
}

li > div {
  display: inline-block   /* Aligns date and content on the same line */
}

.date:after {
  content: " - "          /* Adds a hyphen after each date */
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none   /* Removes the default ul bullet point */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><div class="date">1943</div><div class="content">ipsum derigam sursus versum</div></li>
  <li><div class="date">1964</div><div class="content">ipsum sharingan leviosa</div></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It was exactly what I needed, thanks! I didn't know you could style lists like this

Comment: @AlejandroRosales You can style virtually anything.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        b:after {
            content: '-';
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <b>1943 </b>
            <span> ipsum derigam sursus versum</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <b>1975 </b>
            <span> ipsum sharingan leviosa</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope it can help you.